# Is there a free version of ExtJS 5?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In the past I have used ExtJS 4 for several projects.
Can we download and use ExtJS 5 for a not commercial project for free?
I see in their website there is no free version but I thought that they have a GPL license.

Comment: Although this question isn't a great fit for SO, see [this page](https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/) (and make sure you understand the licensing terms).

Comment: This question appears to be off topic? What about this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298621/is-extjs-open-source Seriously you seem a bit confused lately guys. How this: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" relates to my question?  Did I ask you to recommend or to find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sencha does provide a GPL-licensed version of ExtJS.](https://www.sencha.com/legal/gpl/) However, you must abide by the linked licensing terms. Based on your question details, writing a closed source, commercial product would directly violate these terms:

> - If you create software that uses GPL, you must release your source code (see GPL FAQ), and
> - If you start with a GPL license, you cannot convert to a commercial license simply by purchasing one.
>
> **You cannot include Sencha Ext JS or Sencha GXT in a closed source distribution under this license.**

On that same page, it says:

> If you choose to pay for a [Commercial License](https://www.sencha.com/legal/), you are not required to disclose your source code.

If you choose to purchase the commercial license, you are required to purchase 5 developer licenses minimum.

[More helpful Sencha licensing information](https://www.sencha.com/legal/sencha-software-license-agreement/)

Comment: To be fair, there's no indication in the question that states they are intending to keep it closed-source. (It just says non-commercial)

Comment: @Phylogenesis you are right. Whenever I think of commercial, I immediately think of closed source. I did link to licensing information, which links to the specific GPL license they are using.

Comment: This question appears to be off topic? What about this one: stackoverflow.com/questions/1298621/is-extjs-open-source Seriously you seem a bit confused lately guys. How this: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow" relates to my question? Did I ask you to recommend or to find anything?

Comment: @dkar Although I did see the question as not typical of SO, I was able to find the answer quickly enough for you.

Comment: @Hunter Stevens tell me please how this question: stackoverflow.com/questions/1298621/is-extjs-open-source gets upvoted and how my question gets downvoted. I am not looking for any free points here but you have to admit that this is at least awkward.

Comment: @dkar You cannot compare your question to one from _six years ago_. Much has changed about guidelines since then. Like I said, I agree with the votes to close, but I felt that this was simple enough to answer. Furthermore, if you read, the old question was closed June 2015.

Comment: oh well. who cares about the digital world and the points of it. We only live once.